# A word that describes something as simple, yet effective

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that describes something as simple, yet effective in picking up the nuances of something else. For example: "Disclosure makes **__** electronic music, as their songs are simple pops songs with the nuances of good electronic music." Or, to put it differently: "the solution was simple yet drew upon all essential elements of the issue."

Comment: How about [*elegant*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/elegant): Characterised by minimalism and intuitiveness while preserving exactness and precision. ?

Comment: Elegant means just that in math, but it really just means "tasteful".  It has the meaning you cite across various disciplines because they are strongly affected by mathematical taste.

Comment: just FWIW the acronym "KISS" is sometimes relevant in this sort of discussion.  I use "natty" or "poetic" in the sentence you offer.

Answer (score 2):

Elegant.

"This brief book is elegant and surprising."

Answer (score 1):

Consider: **Ingenious**:

cleverly and originally devised and well suited to its purpose.[Ingenious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ingenious?q=ingenious)

Answer (score 0):

"Cogent" might be appropriate.

Comment: Please provide an example, a quote, or a reference in order to assist the OP. Thank you!